# regex validation for input text field

Tags: javascript

I have to write a regex to make the input text field alphanumeric and do not allow hyphen at the beginning and at the end but can accept hyphen at the middle of the string

Comment: Welcome to SO, please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read through the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular *[How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)* Do your research, [search](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. If you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: Here is an excellent good tool to build and test regex: https://regex101.com

Comment: Also worth mentionning that there is a MDN page explaining everything that needs to be known about [JavaScript regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp).

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex `[a-zA-Z0-9]([a-zA-Z0-9\-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])?`

```js
var pattern=/[a-zA-Z0-9]([a-zA-Z0-9\-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])?/g;

console.log(pattern.test("ab1"));
console.log(pattern.test("-sd"));
console.log(pattern.test("a-1"));
console.log(pattern.test("d-"));
```

Explanation of regex:-

```
[a-zA-Z0-9]    ---> first character must be alphnumeric
[a-zA-Z0-9\-]* ---> zero or more character which is alphanumeric and -
[a-zA-Z0-9]    ---> last character must be alphnumeric
([a-zA-Z0-9\-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])?  ---> either no character or last character must be alphanumeric and all the other alphanumeric and -
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I tried it in fiddle .It is not accepting hyphen at the beginning and the end , but it is also not accepting hyphen in the middle of the string . It has to accept hyphen in the middle of the string

Comment: Thanks Yajiv my mistake! the solution you gave works. the regex i am trying with is "/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+(-[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*$/i"